# Fire multiple requests with URLConnection socket flush

Tags: java, sockets, urlconnection

What did wrong here? I want to send multiple messages in one https connection with URLConnection. I only get the first message on server.

```
    URL url = new URL("https://example.com:443");
    URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
    connection.setDoOutput(true);

    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(
            new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream()));

    out.write("Hello");
    out.flush();

    inReader = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));

    out.write("Response");
    out.flush();

    inReader = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));

    out.write("Response2");
    out.flush();

    inReader = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));

    out.write("Response3");
    out.flush();

    inReader = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));

    inReader.close();

    out.close();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't. `URLConnection` is for HTTP, which is a stateless protocol. Not for your own stateful messaging protocol. One request and one response. If you want to send another message, get a new `URLConnection`. Connection pooling will probably happen behind the scenes.

You also need to read the response. Merely getting the input stream is not sufficient, and getting it multiple times is pointless.

Hard to see why you are writing `"Response"` in a request.

Comment: I'm doing some research about old beast attack and there the researcher had told that : "I could open a request, append more data to it as long as I want, and each time I "flush" the output stream, Java would send out a record in the same SSL connection." With which connection i can do such thing? Because there he told that used URLConnection

Comment: 'Append more data' is not the same as what you're doing. You are trying to send multiple requests. If you remove all the `getInputStream()` calls except the last, you will be 'appending more data'.

Answer (score -1):

Try this way, use HttpURLConnection instead (sample code edited):

```
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL("https://example.com:443").openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
connection.setDoInput(true);
connection.setDoOutput(true);
connection.setChunkedStreamingMode(1024);
connection.connect();

try (OutputStream out = connection.getOutputStream()) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        String msg = "hello" + i + System.lineSeparator();
        out.write(msg.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    }
}

try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8))) {
    // messages sent back end with lineSeparator
    reader.lines().filter(StringUtils::isNotEmpty).forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

For further infomation you might want to checkout the docstring of `setChunkedStreamingMode` or other streamingMode provided

reference: https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-5026745

------------------------------------- edited based on user207421's reply

I realized that your question might be different from the question in the reference link above, so streamingMode might not be something you are looking for.

I updated the sample code above to send multiple messages separated by lineSeparator, and receive multiple messages in the same way.
I couldn't find a way to send a message based on the previous response that is similar to your case.

Hope it helps a bit.

Comment: Please explain the difference between this and what he is already doing, and how it solves the problem. And specifically, please explain how this code can send multiple messages over an `HttpURLConnection`, which it can't, as it is impossible.

Comment: The main difference is the 'ChunkedStreamingMode' I mentioned above. It means sending data in chunked way. In the sample code above, when sending multiple messages or large data, the code will flush immediently after buffering 1024 bytes. Also, I do not get your point why it is impossible to send multiple messages. As long as we serialize and deserialize properly (ndjson for example) I think it is ok to send multiple messages.

Comment: In other words you haven't even tried what the OP is attempting. When and if you do, you will find that chunked streaming mode makes no difference to the impossibility of the problem whatsoever.

Comment: I edited my answer which might relate more to the OP's question. Thanks to your comments

Comment: "I couldn't find a way to send a message based on the previous response": exactly, so you haven't answered the question, so your answer should be deleted.